# How to stop configurable and simple product to add to cart together in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

Hello i want to do if there is simple product is added in cart then when customer is try to add configurable product then they should get message "you can't add configurable product with simple product please remove simple product from cart and then add the configurable product" i want this functionality how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use event ***checkout_cart_save_before***, and check the current adding product to the existing ones and apply conditions as per your need and set the message.